# Facebook retargeting pixel

Tags: web-browser, cookies, facebook, user-tracking, tracking

Given a commercial website `buy.com` and a user with a Facebook account in `facebook.com`, the user has third-party cookies disabled in the browser.

If a user is logged in their Facebook account and visits `facebook.com`, Facebook can set **first-party cookies** for `facebook.com`

Now the user visits `buy.com`, the site uses a **web beacon** with an `<img>` tag with `src` pointing to a `facebook.com` URL.

Can the user can still be tracked and a retargeting campaign can happen without consent?

Assumption is that the request from the `<img>` tag on the `buy.com` site, sends info about the visit on the URL and is able to trace it back to the original user thanks to the **first-party cookies** that were set by the visit to Facebook and get **resent** on the request for the **web beacon** even from a different domain. Is that correct?

Comment: I've removed the part about being legal since this is off-topic here. Use [law.se] for legal questions instead. Also, traditionally all cookies are the same and this will be possible. Some browsers though treat cookies differently depending if first-party or not and also other criteria. So the answer depends likely on the exact browser you use.

Comment: This depends on whether the browser has first-party isolation enabled. With such isolation there isn't a global cookie jar, but one jar per origin you navigate to. Then, your FB cookies on facebook.com would be unrelated to your FB cookies for requests caused by an example.com first-party. Without such isolation the subresource request to the pixel would allow for tracking, but browsers differ in what referral information they supply. Of course, arbitrary tracking info can be encoded into the pixel URL

Comment: @amon did not know about the isolation option, I will look into it